# how i can i change the content of a page without refreshing

Tags: php, javascript

how i can i change the content of a page without refreshing.I know we need to use hidden frames for this but all the tutorials i have come across teach this only for HTML files what if the content is returned from a PHP file how do i do it in such a case? what should the php file echo or return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a hidden frame, the content won't be displayed (hence "hidden"), I think you just mean to use an iframe. But this doesn't fit your description of "without refreshing", since you have to refresh the frame.

When loading the PHP file inside the frame, your PHP file just needs to generate HTML the same way you would generate a normal page. It's the same whether the PHP file is loaded inside a frame or not.

Comment: I believe he is referring the hidden frame AJAX pattern, where a hidden frame is used to handle the HTTP request. This pattern is sometimes used when the developer wants to allow the user to make use of the back/forward buttons in the browser to return to different states.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for that, have a look at this tutorial:

- [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp)

Answer (score 1):

I use this method for a lot of my websites and so does Google. If you want to get data from a PHP file and then dynamically update the page you need to "import" the PHP file somehow without the entire page being redirected, or using iframes (which works too but is a lot messier). The way you do this is to import the file as a "javascript" file.

The following code demonstrates a form called "testform" and a text input called "userpost".
When you submit the form, it will import a file, and then update div "outputText" with whatever you entered... and wait for it... all without the page being redirected at all or refreshed!

I have included a lot of extra functions to show how you can access all of your functions on the same DOM unlike if you use frames where you have to use "top.*object*" or what not

---

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>

    // Get objects by their id. We will use this in the PHP imported file
    Get = function(id) {
      return (!id) ? null : (typeof id == "object") ? id : 
      (document.getElementById) ? document.getElementById(id) : 
      (document.all) ? document.all[id] :
      (document.layers) ? document.layers[id] : null;
    }

    // Formats a string so it does not break in a URL
    String.prototype.formatForURL = function() {
      var str = escape(this.replace(/ /gi, "%20"));
      str = str.replace(/\&/gi, "%26").replace(/\=/gi, "%3D");
      str = str.replace(/\//gi, "%2F")
      return str;
    }

    String.prototype.contains = function(str) {
      return (!str) ? false : (this.indexOf(str) > -1);
    }

    Object.prototype.killself = function() {
      this.offsetParent.removeChild(this);
    }

    // Import the script
    ImportScript = function(js) {
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      script.setAttribute("language", "JavaScript");
      script.setAttribute("charset", "utf-8");
      // we add the is tag so can delete the "js" file as soon as it executes
      script.setAttribute("id", "import_" + head.children.length);
      script.setAttribute("src", js + (js.contains("?") ? "" : "?") + "&is=" + head.children.length);
      head.appendChild(script);
    }

    // Get and send value to php file
    sendInfo = function() {
      var file = "js/myFile.php?userpost=";
      file += document.testform.userpost.value.formatForURL();
      ImportScript(file);
    }

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
     <form name=testform onsubmit="sendInfo(); return false">
       <input type=TEXT name=userpost />
       <input type=SUBMIT value=Go />
     </form>
    </div>
    <div id=ouputText>
      This text will be replaced by what you type 
      and submit into the form above
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

---

### js/myFile.php

```
<?php

  // Here you can now use functions like mysql_connect() etc. even exec()
  // ANYTHING! Save them into variables and output them as text which goes
  // Straight into the javascript! e.g. :
  // $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
  // if($con) {
  //   ... code to retrieve data and save into $variable 
  // }
  // print "alert(\"$variable\");"; // this alerts the value in variable

  if(isset($_GET['userpost'])) {
    $userpost = $_GET['userpost'];
?>
  Get("outputText").innerHTML = "<?=$userpost; ?>";
<?php
  }
?>

// Clear text area
document.testform.userpost.setAttribute("value", "");

// Remove the file from header after info is changed
Get("import_<?=$_GET['is']; ?>").killself();
```

If I had typed in "Hello World" into text input "userpost" then
div "outputText" would be filled with the words "Hello World" 
deleting what was previously there, and the text input will be cleared

Answer (score 0):

Hidden frames is one design pattern that is a part of the overall AJAX design pattern. This is an extreme high-level overview, but this is essentially how it works:

1. Javascript in your HTML page makes a request to your PHP script by using an XMLHTTPRequest object, or a hidden frame or iframe. This is usually done asynchronously, so you can continue to work with your HTML page while the request is being made.
2. The data is returned to your Javascript. At this point, you can then manipulate the page, and update data on the page using various DOM methods.